# Where do set scala and java versions in a multi-module sbt project?

Tags: scala, sbt

My sbt project is based on this layout: [Confused how to setup a multi project sbt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188771/confused-how-to-setup-a-multi-project-sbt-project)

How and where exactly should I set the scala and java version?

I'm currently have problems with java versions when deploying so I need to be more explicit about it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to add this to `Commons.settings` (`scalaVersion := "2.11.1"`). You can still override the versions in project specific settings later.

It will look like this:

```
val settings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
  version := appVersion,
  resolvers += Opts.resolver.mavenLocalFile,
  scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
)
```

And to override:

```
lazy val appWeb = (project in file("app-web")).
  settings(Commons.settings: _*).
  settings(playScalaSettings: _*).
  settings(scalaVersion := "2.10.3").
  dependsOn(appServices)
```

I'm not sure how you want to set the Java version though. But there's a [post about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208942/enforcing-java-version-for-scala-project-in-sbt)