# SBT - missing dependency

Tags: scala, sbt

Well, my collaborator run code under build.sbt shown below without any problems while I get:

```
[error] /.../GameMap.scala:91: value revalidate is not a member of javax.swing.JFrame
[error]     frame.revalidate()
[error]           ^
[error] /.../GameMap.scala:92: value revalidate is not a member of java.awt.Container
[error]     frame.getContentPane.revalidate()
[error]                          ^
```

I suspect, something is missing in build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature")                                                                                                                                    

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.8",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % "2.3.8",
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.10.4"
)
```

What is it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your running Java 6 and your collaborator is running Java 7

[This is the Container documentation for java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html), which does not list a `revalidate` method inherited from `Component`.

[And here is the java 7 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html), which DOES list a `revalidate` method being inherited from `Component`

*The same can be stated for `swing`

Comment: Is it possible to add whole java7 (like single jar) to sbt ?

Comment: I don't believe so, but you could add `scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.7"` to get a better error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208942/enforcing-java-version-for-scala-project-in-sbt